# Downloading GitHub Java Projects to Netbeans

Tags: java, github, netbeans

Today I was trying to download source code from GitHub at https://github.com/lukstei/trading-backtest
and I came across a problem.

When I went to NetBeans and imported the zip file, it said no new NetBeans projects were created. The folder for the project was created but when trying to `Open Project`, the folder was not detected as a `project folder`.

Any help on downloading or using these files would be helpful, as this is my first time using GitHub.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The trading-backtest project is built with gradle so try installing the [Netbeans Gradle Support Plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support).